# .htaccess to redirect certain areas to https

Tags: regex, .htaccess, https

What I'm trying to do is serve the folder /soap OR pages that have /?p=uploads in title over http, the rest of the site over https.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(p=uploads)(&|$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^soap/?(.*) http://www.example.com/soap/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/soap

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

It seems to work for the soap folder but not pages with /?p=uploads

Comment: You should use `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` or `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` instead of server port.

Comment: ¿`/soap` **AND** `...pages that have /?p=uploads`? ¿Both conditions have to be met or any of them will do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !soap/?      [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !p=uploads/? [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://www.example.com/$1    [L,R=301,QSA]
```

All URLs are redirected to HTTPS, except those that have `/soap` or  `/?p=uploads`

Comment: This is still forcing /?p=uploads over https

Comment: Please give an example of the complete URL when it fails to skip the rule.

Comment: @Zeb99 ¿Did you remove all the rules in your question? They are not needed.

Comment: Yes, I'm just using you example for now - with just example.com changed.

Comment: You know I'm not all together sure! The address bar still shows https://example.com/?p=uploads  - so I simply had to fix the upload script to work over https   - the /soap folder does revert to http as required though.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry Faa, thought I had it fixed. Have tested it in chrome and the uploads doesnt work over https. Any further ideas why the /?p=uploads isnt redirecting to plain http?

Comment: @Zeb99 Sorry, I didn't remember what was the question about. I was reading it again and the presence of the string `p=upload` in the query should force to skip the rule as `soap` does. But I will modify my answer to try another option.

Comment: Updated. Please try again.

Comment: Sorry, example.com/?p=uploads   still redirecting to https

Comment: @Zeb99 To be completely sure, I tested the rule in several servers and several conditions and never redirected to HTTPS. I really don't understand what is happening in this case. The modifications I made are irrelevant because it worked fine as it was too. If `soap` works, the other should work too. There is something I am missing. ¿Are you testing in a local server, did you make sure the browser's cache is cleared? Chrome has a very sticky cache hard to remove. ¿Is there any possibility that another rule is previously redirecting the URL with `p=uploads` or any query to HTTPS?

Comment: Remote sever, cache cleared. No other url rule Im aware of. Appreciated all the help Faa; will let you know what the issue was once I crack it.